# Add a "place you dislike" to the job matches

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm currently playing around with the "Match Preferences".
And one thing I found out, is that it makes appear a lot of jobs in towns I wouldn't want to work in (because reasons).

I would like to have a filter with "place you dislike" like there is a "tech you dislike". Thus the the "match" algorithm will avoid those places (except if the offer allow remote work, making it so you don't have to move there).

Comment: But what if the job of your dreams, with awesome coworkers, the best chairs, and the best tech just *happens* to be in North Korea?